# .htaccess 301 redirect that excludes a subpage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page-parent.*$ http://www.domain.com/new-page/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

My issue is that there is a page /page-parent/thanks that I don't want to be redirect.

I am also passing the query string along so that any ?gclid= string will go with.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to exclude a single sub page or all sub pages, which would work too.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to create a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page-parent/thanks
RewriteRule ^page-parent.*$ http://www.domain.com/new-page/ [R=301,L]
```

Note that you can leave out the `?%{QUERY_STRING}` from your target, because query strings are appended to the target by default unless you've added new params via a **?**.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with a `RewriteCond` if the requested page is the page you want to exclude.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page-parent/thanks
RewriteRule ^page-parent.*$ http://www.domain.com/new-page/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Make sure that you clean the browser cache when retrying since 301-redirects get cached.

Note: You don't need to append the query string manually.

Comment: Jon Lin beat you by like 30 seconds