# Redirect all pages to a subpage but ignore specific pages

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all pages for a domain to a subpage called 'emergency'.

However ignore two specific pages - the 'emergency' page itself and another page called 'system'.

I currently have:

```
    AcceptPathInfo On

    Options -Indexes

    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(emergency|system)/?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /emergency? [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|cgi-bin|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This does **not** work.

I have already looked at, but could not get anything working either:

- [Apache redirect all sub pages to home page except specific pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123744/apache-redirect-all-sub-pages-to-home-page-except-specific-pages)
- [.htaccess 301 redirect that excludes a subpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022244/htaccess-301-redirect-that-excludes-a-subpage)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a leading slash after `^`

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(emergency|system)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /emergency? [L,R=301]
```

**Your full and corrected .htaccess**

```
AcceptPathInfo On

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|emergency|system)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /emergency? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|cgi-bin|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I now get redirected to domain.com/emergency but I get: "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: do you have some other rule there also? Post your full .htaccess

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(emergency|system)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /emergency? [L,R=301]

AcceptPathInfo On
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On  
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|cgi-bin|favicon\.ico)
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
      RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`

Comment: I am on mobile now. Please edit the question and provide this code there since reading it from comments is very difficult.

Comment: Yes. domain.com/emergency